# adding an animated border to li in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a bottom border for each `li` item in my `navbar`. However, the border creates a separate line below the actual content of the `li` items even when I have given the `div.nav-line` class inside the li tags.

```js
   $(function() {
        $(".dropdown").hover(
            function() { $(this).addClass('open') },
            function() { $(this).removeClass('open') }
        );
    });
```

```css
.navbar {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #b4a28f;
}

.navbar-nav>li>.nav-line {
  background-color: #3178b9;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  /*        -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        transition: all 100ms ease-out;*/
}

.navbar-nav>li:hover>.nav-line {
  background-color: #3178b9;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <!-- <img class="img img-responsive" src="www/images/srs-logo.jpg" alt="SRS Constructions"> -->
        SRS Constructions
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a class="main" href="#main">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown" id="nav-about">
          <a href="#about" class="dropdown-toggle main" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About
                            </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left:0;right: auto">
            <li><a href="about.html">The Founder</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="health-policy.html">HSE Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="quality-policy.html">Quality Policy</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="main" href="#services">Services</a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="main" href="#projects">Our Projects</a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="main" href="#whyus">Why Us</a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="main" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

1. I want the border to appear inside the li container so that there is no extra line which spans the whole navbar (the background color on hover does not cover the full height of the li item, since the line of 2px is present.) .
2. I do not want the line for the `active` li item.

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try `box-sizing: border-box` ? This is the right way to keep content inside itselft: Specify that <div> elements should have padding and border included in the element's total width and height: Check this: [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: tried adding it to the style for `nav-line`. It did not change anything

Comment: Do you mean the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the following code should be good for you to use:

I have added the following - relative positioning to li, absolute positioning to navline, and then transparent background for the active navline

```js
$(function() {
        $(".dropdown").hover(
            function() { $(this).addClass('open') },
            function() { $(this).removeClass('open') }
        );
    });
```

```css
.navbar {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  min-height: 80px;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
    position:relative;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 80px;
}

.dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #b4a28f;
}

.navbar-nav>li>.nav-line {
  position:absolute; 
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  background-color: #3178b9;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  /*        -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        transition: all 100ms ease-out;*/
}
.navbar-nav>li:hover>.nav-line {
  background-color: #3178b9;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in;
}


.navbar-nav>li.active>.nav-line {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <!-- <img class="img img-responsive" src="www/images/srs-logo.jpg" alt="SRS Constructions"> -->
        SRS Constructions
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a class="main" href="#main">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown" id="nav-about">
          <a href="#about" class="dropdown-toggle main" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About
                            </a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="left:0;right: auto">
            <li><a href="about.html">The Founder</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="health-policy.html">HSE Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="quality-policy.html">Quality Policy</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="main" href="#services">Services</a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="main" href="#projects">Our Projects</a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="main" href="#whyus">Why Us</a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="main" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          <div class="nav-line"></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your snippet still has the extra line below the `li` items. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were on about the about li navline appearing at the bottom - can you elaborate as it is not clear what you want - where do you want the nav-line to appear

Comment: For each li item , I want the nav-line to appear on hover. However , there is an line which spans the whole navbar even when the line is not hovered. I do not want that line like that and I want that line to be contained inside the li tag - without creating a line of 2px under the whole navbar.

Comment: @v1shnu check the edit - is that what you are after?

Comment: yes this is what I want. can you please tell me what change have you done to remove the 2px added to the navbar below ?

Comment: I added relative positioning to the li and then made the navline absolutely positioned to the bottom -1px as it seemed to leave a line once it had animated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145010/discussion-between-v1shnu-and-pete).

Answer (score 0):

Add this in CSS.

.navbar-nav li.active a.main {
    display: none
}

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. I think your answer only addresses the line to not appear for the active element.